# I want to know more about self join and how > < <> operate

Tags: sql

products

[image]

```
SELECT P1.name AS name_1, P2.name AS name_2
FROM Products P1, Products P2
WHERE P1.name > P2.name
```

I wonder how “P1.name > P2.name” Perform operations, 
this is not the number, why does it scale? Thanks!

Comment: Use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators work on most data types, including numbers, strings, and dates.

For strings, this would be based on the *collation* of the strings.  That is the technical term for defining the ordering of strings.  (You can look it up in your database documentation or on Wikipedia.)

For most practical purposes, the collation is the ordering as defined in the dictionary.  So, the comparisons are alphabetical comparisons -- for whatever "alphabet" means for the language you are using.

Note that you can express your logic using an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT P1.name AS name_1, P2.name AS name_2
FROM Products P1 JOIN
     Products P2
     ON P1.name > P2.name;
```